# how to parse a string with escaped json using dataweave 2.0

Tags: json, parsing, dataweave, mule4

I need to parse the response of an API that is like this:

```
"[{\"Customers\":[{\"Id\":1607715391563}],\"Partners\":[],\"ModDate\":\"\\/Date(1608031919597)\\/\",\"CreatedByUserId\":null},{\"Message\":null,\"Code\":\"200\",\"NextPage\":1}]"
```

I wish I have it like this:

```
[
   {
      "Customers":[
         {
            "Id":1607715391563
         }
      ],
      "Partners":[
         
      ],
      "ModDate":"/Date(1608031919597)/",
      "CreatedByUserId":null
   },
   {
      "Message":null,
      "Code":"200",
      "NextPage":1
   }
]
```

I already tried to remove the strings using `payload[1 to -2]`, and parse the JSON using `read(payload[1 to -2], 'application/json')`. I already tried to follow some tips of this [link](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXXLXSA4/mule-4-how-to-parse-an-escaped-json-string) but neither worked.

**EDIT:**
The point here is that I want to access, for example, Customers.Id value in other connector, and I can't

Comment: The input is not 'slashed' JSON but a JSON input that has been escaped.

Comment: aled, thanks for your comment, I changed the title

Comment: Hi mhery. Where does this string comes from? Maybe you just need to set the proper Mime Type in the origin. If it's not possible to solve it in the origin, Salim's solution looks like the better approach.

Comment: Jorge, thanks for your comment. Salim's solution worked well here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this?

[image]

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inpString = "[{\"Customers\":[{\"Id\":1607715391563}],\"Partners\":[],\"ModDate\":\"\\/Date(1608031919597)\\/\",\"CreatedByUserId\":null},{\"Message\":null,\"Code\":\"200\",\"NextPage\":1}]"
---
read(inpString,"application/json")
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The problem is that for some reason the input is an escaped JSON document. Using read() to parse it returns the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read((payload replace /^"|"$/ with '') replace '\"' with '"', "application/json")
```

The first replace will remove heading and trailing double quotes, and the second one will replace back slash scaped double quotes by double quotes.

Comment: olamiral, thanks for your answer. Although this works, what I need is to access for example Customers.Id value and I still cant with your expression

Comment: Hi, mhery! You can verify that this answers exactly what was asked in your question. Could you please update your question to reflect what you're really trying to achieve? Thank you.

Comment: sorry olamiral, it was my mistake here. your code actually works!